# Resizing an Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm searching for few days and I can't find the answer. I'm trying to resize an Image View through XML.

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/header" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/logo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/iconwide" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></ImageView>
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/user" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/user" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/suser" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

Any idea how to resize it ? It looks like this: http://i55.tinypic.com/2h3u4hh.png

Comment: How do you want it resized? To a specific size? To be the size of the image?

Comment: For a specific size, provide a specific size instead of "match_parent". Try "100dp" for layout_height and see what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like a specific size, you can specify that size via XML by using [density independent pixels](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence). On a mdpi screen, 1 dp = 1 pixel, on all screens 100dp is roughly equal to 1 inch.

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/iconwide"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```